# Recursive CTE increases time

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I just made this code, the My_View table has about 9,000 rows, the CTE one has about 14,000. And CTE's first iteration lasted about 0,5s (Handwritting the code), but with the recursion, it lasts about 5 min. The main problem should be at the recursive code, but it shouldn't.

The objective of the code is: Having the following data:

{ID}  [Primary ID] [Secondary ID]

Where all the Primary ID's begin with C... And the Secondary ID's with K... The problem is that some Secondary ID's are a link to a Primary ID as following:

```
{ID} [C010] [K011]
{ID} [C020] [C010]
{ID} [C020] [K020]

So what I want is it to finish like:
{ID} [C010] [K011]
{ID} [C020] [K011]
{ID} [C020] [K020]

{ID} = {[Cod_ 1], [First year], [First month]}

WITH CTE AS (   SELECT DISTINCT [Cod_ 1], [First year], [First month], [Primary ID], [Secondary ID]     FROM My_View    WHERE [Secondary ID] LIKE 'K%'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT m1.[Cod_ 1], m1.[First year], m1.[First month], m1.[Primary ID], [m2.Secondary ID]   FROM My_View m1 INNER JOIN CTE m2 ON m1.[Cod_ 1] = m2.[Cod_ 1] AND m1.[First year] = m2.[First year] AND m1.[First month] = m2.[First month] AND m1.[Secondary ID] = m2.[Primary ID]

    )

    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM CTE
    ORDER BY [Cod_ 1], [Primary ID], [Secondary ID]
```

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add `WHERE` condition like

```
WHERE m1.[Primary ID] NOT LIKE 'K%'
```

to avoid **recursion-depth** error or **any similar case may slow it**.

So this may help you:

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Cod_ 1]
        ,[First year]
        ,[First month]
        ,[Primary ID]
        ,[Secondary ID]
    FROM My_View
    WHERE [Secondary ID] LIKE 'K%'
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT m1.[Cod_ 1]
        ,m1.[First year]
        ,m1.[First month]
        ,m1.[Primary ID]
        ,[m2.Secondary ID]
    FROM My_View m1
    INNER JOIN CTE m2 ON m1.[Cod_ 1] = m2.[Cod_ 1]
        AND m1.[First year] = m2.[First year]
        AND m1.[First month] = m2.[First month]
        AND m1.[Secondary ID] = m2.[Primary ID]
    WHERE m1.[Primary ID] NOT LIKE 'K%'
    )
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM CTE
ORDER BY [Cod_ 1]
    ,[Primary ID]
    ,[Secondary ID]
```